# Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile not showing all subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

The Azure powershell command Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile is downloading only 2 of my 3 subscriptions. Why?

In powersheel, I'm running this command:

```
PS C:\> Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile
```

That command opens the following webpage:
https://manage.windowsazure.com/publishsettings/index?client=powershell

The webpage creates a file *.PublishSettings. That file only contains settings for 2 of my 3 subscrptions. The subscriptions all appear to be configured in the same manner.

Comment: If you run: Get-AzureSubscription cmdlet, are you able to get all 3 of your subscriptions?

Comment: Yes, I can see all 3 subscriptions. And they have the same values for properties Environment, SupportedModes, DefaultAccount, Accounts, CurrentStorageAccountName, and TenantId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this workaround-

Set your azure subscription to current to  one  which doesn't appear in your publishsetting file

```
select-azuresubscription -subscriptionname "Yoursubname" -current
```

and then run

`Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile`

Comment: Select-AzureSubscription does not affect the subscriptions that get returned by Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile.

Comment: You are right. But, once you select the subscription to current, it sets selected subscription name to your current. Now when you run the Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile it fetches  and adds details of the current subscription to the pubshishsetting file and then adds the other subscription to publishsetting file. I have faced the same issue in past and it worked for me. This is just a workaround.